# Ethereum Solidity - Does require() use any gas?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

Google has failed to give me an concrete answer, does using the `require()` function in `Solidity` use up any gas? Even if the statement in the function is evaluated as true?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if you're asking if the OPCODE itself consumes gas or if gas is consumed if the statement evaluates to true.

If you're asking about the OPCODE itself, I agree with you that the answer is unclear. I don't see the `REVERT` OPCODE (which is what `require()` is compiled to) in the (now very deprecated) [Google OPCODE gas usage spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m89CVujrQe5LAFJ8-YAUCcNK950dUzMQPMJBxRtGCqs/edit#gid=0) or in the [yellowpaper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) (Appendix G).

Running a test in Remix, it looks like it does consume a very small amount of gas. Simply adding a `require(true)` call at the top of this method increased gas usage by 23.

```
contract GasUsage {
    uint val;

    function someFunc() public returns (bool) {
        require(true);

        delete val;
    }
}
```

Execution cost when included:5230

Execution cost when commented out: 5207

---

If you're asking about gas consumption up until the `require` statement, then the answer is yes. As of the [Byzantium](https://blog.ethereum.org/2017/10/12/byzantium-hf-announcement/) release, all gas consumed up to the point of a `require` statement is consumed, but any remaining gas is returned. Prior to Byzantium, `require()` and `assert()` were identical and all gas would be consumed.

From the [Solidity docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions):

> Internally, Solidity performs a revert operation (instruction 0xfd)
>   for a require-style exception and executes an invalid operation
>   (instruction 0xfe) to throw an assert-style exception. In both cases,
>   this causes the EVM to revert all changes made to the state...Note that assert-style exceptions consume all gas
>   available to the call, while require-style exceptions will not consume
>   any gas starting from the Metropolis release.

Answer (score 2):

`require` does not use gas in case of failure but uses if it is evaluated `true`. In case of failure, the state is reverted and "UNUSED" gas is returned. However, it does not return already consumed gas.

```
function test() public view {
    // some function logic;
    require(condition,"")
}
```

In this case if `require` fails, the gas that used to execute "some function logic" will not be reverted. That is why `require` is used at the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Complementing the previous answer, nowadays it is already possible to check the `REVERT` OPCODE in https://www.evm.codes/ and the minimum gas is 0.